# In what order the code execution takes place

Tags: javascript

```
var i = 1;
undefined
console.log(i++ + ++i + i)
VM71:1 7
undefined
```

I saw a similar question somewhere and I tried it on dev console .

So in what order the code execution takes place
What I thought would be was 5 
ie `1 + 2 + 2`

`1 + 3 + 3` is what I think happened .

So how the following sequence was executed by javascript compiler

Comment: `i++ + ++i + i` -> `1 + 3 + 3`

Comment: can you please explain this a bit as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the specifics of [operator precedence here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), but essentialy what's happening is i++ will evaluate to 1, and then increment, so i will be 2, then ++i will increment first, so will evaluate to 3, then i is 3 so you get 1+3+3 since pre and post fix increments are done before addition.

Comment: I wanted to make sure if that's how it executed .I was reading operator precedence manual to confirm it and was somewhat confused

Answer (score 2):

The rules for [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) are well-defined. Postfix increment has the highest precedence of the three operators used in your expression:

```
Precedence | Operator          | Syntax
17         | Postfix Increment | … ++
16         | Prefix Increment  | ++ …
13         | Addition          | … + …
```

So in order, the steps are:

```
((i++) + (++i)) + i // i === 1
( 1    + (++i)) + i // i === 2, postfix increment
( 1    +    3 ) + i // i === 3, prefix increment
4               + 3 // i === 3, addition
7                   // i === 3, addition
```

Answer (score 1):

It's evaluated left-to-right:

```
(i++ + ++i + i)
```

- `i++` is evaluated to be 1, and `i` is incremented.
- then, `++i` is evaluated to be 3, and `i` is incremented.
- then, `i` is evaluated to be 3.

Precedence determines the grouping of operands with operators, not the evaluation order. For example, `i + i + ++i` would not increment `i` before the addition.